# How to reduce the memory use during building index in pouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using pouchDB in indexdb inside Android webview. Below is the command I used to build the index the first time after syncing database.

```
db.query('my_index', {
                            startkey: ["1111"],
                            endkey: ["1111", {}],
                            include_docs: false
                        });
```

it works well until the database becomes large. It consumes so much memory that it crash the android app. I wonder is there another way to build the index as batch steps? Like I build the index inside a loop, create index for 1000 documents each time.

If it doesn't work, whether I can build the index on couchdb side then sync to browser? Does couchdb support sync index?

Based on the above code, what fields are indexed? Does above code build index on every fields in the database?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do what you're requesting.  Unless there's a memory leak or other bug, the only reason it should use a lot of memory when doing the index build, is to hold the actual index in memory. And batching, or building the index elsewhere, wouldn't solve that problem--I expect it would still need to load the index into memory to update the index.  How many documents are in your database? The best solution might be to segment your database somehow, so that you have a larger number of smaller indexes.

Comment: The total number of document on database is about 18000. Can I build the index on server side and push to client site?

Comment: No, there is no way to synchronize indexes.

Comment: 18000 sounds tiny. Let's suppose the device has 200MB free memory. Each individual index record would need to use more than 10kb of memory to crash it, right? Are you sure there isn't something else going on?

Comment: I found the problem is the design doc is not synced to pouchdb from couchdb server. Can I set design doc on couchdb side and sync them to pouchdb?